# Definition in Math or Axiom in First-Order Logic

Tags: terminology, first-order-logic

I have been thinking about what definition is in math. For instance, we may define the power set as follows: for a set $x$, the power set of $x$, denoted by $\mathcal{P}\left(x\right)$, satisfies the following relation:

$$\mathcal{P}\left(x\right) = \left\{y \textrm{ is a set}\vert y \subseteq x \right\}.$$

This statement seems to be an axiom about the function symbol $\mathcal{P}$ in first-order logic. So can we say that all definitions in math are essentially axioms about new function or predicate symbols in first-order logic?

Comment: Or relation symbols.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Predicates, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to see it. Relations are just predicates on multiple arguments.

Comment: You need to be careful that your "definition" doesn't make new things provable. (Otherwise it's a definition/axiom hybrid). Specifically, any formula not containing the new symbol but which can be proved from math with the new definition needs to be provable without the definition.

Comment: See [extension by definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions).

Comment: There are two kinds of definitions. The kind that covers the power-set function-symbol is known as definitorial expansion/extension, described at "[How could we formalize the introduction of new notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863150/how-could-we-formalize-the-introduction-of-new-notation)" and also supported in the expected way in [this Fitch-style foundational system](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820).

Comment: The other kind of definition is actually just **∃elim**, which is briefly compared with the first kind of definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2221217/21820). Depending on the exact details of your chosen foundational system, you might actually have ∃elim as intrinsic to FOL (e.g. in the linked Fitch-style system), or it might not (in which case you can be consider it to be definitorial expansion for constant-symbols).