# Can rigorousness be defined rigorously?

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology

In Mathematics, one word I hear thrown around a lot of rigor. But, I actually don't really understand it. How do we know if something is rigorous or not? One may answer if it is done by proof theory like Natural deduction or so , but by what metric would such a proof be more rigorous than an explanation anyone could understand in Natural language?

In a logic video I saw on the internet, the example cited of being Natural language being non rigorous is that sometimes the syntax is ambiguous and can lead to some paradox. But, I feel this is not a very rigorous explanation, on what it means to be rigorous.

In essence, I am asking Can rigorousness be defined rigorously?

---

This question is different from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220437/when-is-a-proof-or-definition-formal?noredirect=1&lq=1) / fails to answer this one, because there the answers discuss classifications of formality in natural language rather than attempting to discuss how one could explain rigor rigorously.

Comment: Reasonable question in itself, but it's opinion-based and already asked before (see duplicate), and the answer is of course "no" but logicians all can classify proofs into the categories listed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2221162/21820) at the linked thread, even if they may not use exactly the same adjectives to describe those categories. The point is that any logician **can** rigorously define each category, but the vague term "rigourous" itself clearly doesn't have a standardized mathematical definition.

Comment: To your edit: As I said already, you **cannot** explain "rigour" rigorously if you refuse to even **define** that term precisely. **Choose one category**, or define your own, but if you refuse to do that then your question is not even about mathematics.

Comment: Well, then that should have been put as answer here then. The other question is only tangentially related to what you said here in the comment. Also I don't quite understand what you mean by 'choosing a category' @user21820

Comment: The community convention is to close as duplicate as long as the target thread covers the issues. We should not repeat content across the site as it leads to a big mess. As for your last question, this site is about mathematics, and you can ask questions about mathematical concepts. The **English** word "rigorous" is **not** a standard mathematical concept. However, the first few categories in the linked answer (absolutely/extremely/obviously/provably formal) can each be given a suitable **precise mathematical definition** (more or less), and you can ask about any one of them.

Comment: You mentioned community, but you uni-laterally closed the question but nonetheless I see your point

Comment: I think you misread my English. There is a community convention. I followed the community convention. It so happens that my rep gives me the right to do it faster, but that has nothing to do with the community convention I stated.

Comment: There is a community convention, but the reality is that it was your interpretation that it was infact covered there and asking this point here again would apparently 'create a mess'

Comment: It is covered there. If that duplicate target didn't exist, your question is still 100% opinion-based and still should be closed. I already did you a favour by pointing you to a whole list of possible mathematically precise notions of rigour backed by actual expertise (you can ask any logician for a second opinion). I assumed you wanted help in understanding "rigour", but your response suggests that you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define “rigorous” as follows:

> A piece of mathematics (for example, a definition, statement of a proposition, or proof) is said to be rigorous when an individual with an appropriate amount of mathematical training could take this piece of mathematics and translate it into a reasonable formal logical system.

This definition, by its nature, is not rigorous (as defined above). In fact, it is somewhat ambiguous, even ignoring that it is impossible to translate it into a formal system.

Here is an example of a rigorous definition:

> A set is said to be a subsingleton when any two elements of the set are equal to each other.

This corresponds to the definitional extension of some sort of set theory (perhaps ZFC) given by $subsingleton(x) :\equiv \forall y \forall z (z \in x \land y \in x \to z = y)$. A trained mathematician would easily be able to translate the definition into this formal definitional extension. Therefore, the definition is rigorous.

An example of a nonrigorous definition would be

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous when you can draw the graph of $f$ with a pencil without lifting the pencil off the paper.

While this definition is intuitive, it gives no clue for how to translate the notion into a formal mathematical language.

An example of a rigorous proof would be the following:

> Theorem: Let $G$ be a group and consider three elements $x, y, z$ of the group. Suppose $x \cdot y = x \cdot z$. Then $y = z$.

Proof: we have $y = e \cdot y = (x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot y = x^{-1} \cdot (x \cdot y) = x^{-1} \cdot (x \cdot z) = (x^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot z = e \cdot z = z$ $\square$

An appropriately trained mathematician would easily be able to turn the above proof into a formal proof in, say, the first-order theory of groups, using the various axioms of a group. Thus, the above proof is a rigorous one.

An example of a non-rigorous proof would be as follows:

> Theorem: any set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ which isn’t empty has a least element.

Proof: let’s suppose $S$ doesn’t have a least element. We can start with an element $s_0 \in S$, then pick some $s_1 < s_0$ such that $s_1 \in S$, then pick $s_2, s_3$, and so on. This gives us an infinite descending sequence of natural numbers. But that is absurd, since natural numbers just don’t work that way. $\square$

This is not a rigorous proof if we are working within the usual realm of mathematics. The part about picking $s_0, s_1$, and so on is perfectly rigorous if we assume the axiom of dependent choice. But what is not rigorous is the hand-wavy argument that we can’t have an infinite descending sequence of natural numbers. We would need to appeal to some axiom or to the definition of “natural number” to draw this conclusion.

But note that many ancient Greeks did essentially take as an axiom that an infinite descending sequence of natural numbers is impossible; if you follow in their footsteps, the proof could be considered rigorous.

The moral of the story is that rigor is, in part, a social construct, but in part rooted in formal logic. Mathematicians have a complex system of conventions for what natural language means, how to phrase logical arguments, what principles or theorems should be considered common knowledge, which steps are simple enough that they can be skipped, and more. Evaluating whether a given proof is rigorous requires knowing the entire context of the proof and is, to some degree, unavoidably subjective.